# Cannot Pardon My Sins

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am in a bit of a predicament to say the least.  I am currently in my second playthrough and, before starting NG+, I had the bright idea of murdering every single NPC in the game.  Needless to say, the game gods were not pleased and I was labeled a "sinner". Regardless I thought to myself: "whatever, I will be fine once I start my next playthrough... I'm sure my slate will be clean."

Oh how wrong I was...

Now, I am getting invaded every 5 minutes by an arbiter out for revenge.  But that's not even the worse part...

After finally making it to

> [Brightstone Cove Tseldora](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Brightstone%20Cove%20Tseldora) (Chapel Threshold)

I met with my good pal

> [Cromwell the Pardoner](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Cromwell+the+Pardoner) *(we go way back)*

However, whenever I try "Ask for pardon", he tells me `you have not sinned`, which is simply wrong...  Not to mention, my Player Info section clearly labels me as a sinner.

Does anyone know of a way to pardon my sins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the wikipedia page for [Cromwell The Pardoner](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/cromwell-the-pardoner)

> pardoning sins is only for undoing NPC hostility and does not remove
>   character status sin

so maybe now that you are in NG+ you have already lost NPC hostility and that's why he cannot do much for you.

However, according to [a reddit's user who did quite a lot of testing](http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/21js81/explanation_of_sin_confirmed_through_testing/) there's a way for you to remove your sinner status:

> Dying to a Blue Sentinel Invader reduces your sin count by exactly 1
>   point.

Comment: Thank you for answering! That's awesome, I didn't know about sin reduction!

Comment: Ah, so the solution is "Die a lot"?

Comment: @Humungus welcome to dark souls :-)

Comment: @Geeo I always it was what happened during the process of solving, not the solution itself. :-P

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm finally sin free!!!  Praise the sun!